# Optimal query for checking login details(username and password)

Tags: mysql, optimization

Which is optimal query for check whether the username ans password present in MySql database.

```
1)SELECT * FROM login_details WHERE username='username' AND password='password'
2)SELECT count(*)FROM login_details WHERE username='username' AND password='password'
3)SELECT count(Username)FROM login_details WHERE username='username' AND password='password'
4)SELECT 1 FROM login_details WHERE username='username' AND password='password'
```

Thanks

Comment: In my experience, unless you are dealing with a HUGE number of records - hundreds of millions - the indexing scheme is far more important than the difference between the queries you suggest. Also, eggyal is right about the storing of hashed passwords!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hopefully `'password'` is actually a [salted hash of the user's password](https://stackoverflow.com/a/477578), and you're passing both literals from your application as [parameters to a prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496).

Assuming that you have an index on `(username, password)`, the "optimum" would be:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM login_details WHERE username = ? AND password = ?
)
```

This way, MySQL [stops searching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html) once it encounters a single result.

Comment: Thanks for answer. In this case which is best the inner query? Any performance difference between Select * , Select count(*) or Select 1 in this inner query?

Comment: [Traditionally, an `EXISTS` subquery starts with `SELECT *`, but it could begin with `SELECT 5` or `SELECT column1` or anything at all. MySQL ignores the `SELECT` list in such a subquery, so it makes no difference.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)